# Ruby select from array where key is like parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of objects that I want to filter by a parameter in the URL.

So for example:

```
@items = items.select { |item| params[:q] == item.name }
```

However this will match EXACT... how can I make it behave as a LIKE?

Comment: What does "as a LIKE" mean? Is "formula" like "or"? Does it make a difference that the parameter is "in the URL" (whatever "the URL" refers to)? This question begs for examples. I've downvoted but will remove it if the question is clarified.

Comment: I'm guessing `params[:q]` and `item.name` are  both strings, but they could be arrays. That needs to be clarified as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@items = items.select { |item| item.name.include?(params[:q]) }
```

Edit:

If you need the matching to be case insensitive.

```
@items = items.select { |item| item.name.downcase.include?(params[:q].downcase) }
```

Comment: Is this case sensitive?

Comment: Yes, it is case sensitive.

Comment: Are you assuming `item.name` is a string or an array? That it's not `item.names` suggests it a string, but we can't be sure. Best to state your assumption with your answer, or, better, ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: Instances of String class also have method `include?` so you can test if string contains given substring. From the original code it is quite obvious that item.name is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp:

```
pattern =  /#{params[:q]}/
@items = items.select { |item| pattern =~ item.name }
```

Comment: `pattern #=> /out/` matches `item.name #=> 'shouting'`. If that's your intention, why did you interpret "as a LIKE" that way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Regexp may be used for substring matchint just as LIKE, can't it? Btw. solution from accepted answer matches out in shouting as well:
`> 'shouting'.include? 'out'
=> true`

Comment: Yes, but "as a LIKE" does not necessarily ask whether `params[:q]` is a substring of `item.name` (if it's a string or an array--we can't be sure). For all we know, `params[:q]` is "like" `item.name` if they are strings having the same numbers of characters. True, we can make inferences form the answer selected by the OP, but that was before you posted your answers, so it doesn't explain why you made the assumption you did. Moreover, many-a-time OPs have selected answers that don't do what they've asked or that are simply incorrect.